# Is it possible to user Solr TermsComponent to return the "n" most frequent indexed terms over a base query?

Tags: solr, faceted-search

We want to be able to return the "n" most frequent indexed terms for certain documents selected from a base query. Is that possible using solar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by turning faceting on and faceting on the field from which you're trying to get the frequently indexed terms. You might actually get more information then you need (Solr will return all terms ordered by frequency rather than the top n):

```
?q=keyword&facet=true&facet.field=myfield
```

If you use `&rows=0` as well then Solr will return only the faceting information and not the actual search results as well.

**EDIT**: Actually, by default Solr returns the top 100 facet terms. Use the `facet.limit` parameter to change this number. So, to return the top *n* terms, do the following:

```
?q=keyword&facet=true&facet.field=myfield&facet.limit=n
```

Use a negative number for `facet.limit` to return all terms. More information here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Gave it a try and seems to be working just fine.

Comment: @rreyes1979, I improved my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks, David. I got a new question which I just posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669343/showing-human-readable-most-frequent-indexed-terms-using-a-stemmed-field-with-so. I was going to ask it here, but thought it could be a separate one. If you could give it a look, it would be a great help for us. Thanks again.

Comment: @rreyes1979, I just saw your question and tried to give a practical answer.