# Showing human readable most frequent indexed terms using a stemmed field with Solr faceted search

Tags: solr, highlighting, faceted-search

We are planning on using Solr to show the users the "n" most frequent terms from a field and we want to apply stemming so that similar terms get grouped.

Now, we need to show the terms to the users but the stemmed terms are not always human readable. Is there any way to get an example of the original terms that got stemmed so that those could be shown to the user?

The only solution we can think of is quering two different fields, one with stemming and one without and then do the matching ourselves. But we think that is going to be expensive (two queries) and may be error prone (the matching may produce errors).

Is there any other way to implement this on Solr? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stemming is applied at both query time *and* index time so I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish what you're trying to do. However, it may be possible, depending on the number of results in your database, to do this by employing a combination of faceting and highlighting. The highlighted term will be the entire matching term rather than the stemmed term (so, for example, the stemmed term might be "associ" but the highlighted terms will be "associated", "association", "associations", etc.). Perhaps what you could do is the following:

```
?q=keyword&facet=true&facet.field=myfield&&facet.limit=20hl=true&hl.fl=myfield&hl.fragsize=0&rows=10
```

Getting 10 rows and examining the highlighted results (by default, these are highlighted using `<em>` `</em>` tags but you can change this by using `hl.simple.pre` and `hl.simple.post` -- for example, using `&hl.simple.pre=[&hl.simple.post=]` would wrap the matching terms in square brackets) should at least give a sample of the "original" matching terms. `hl.fragsize=0` returns the entire field along with highlighting.

Hope this helps. You can read more about highlighting parameters here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

Comment: Once more, thanks David for your quick on the spot answers. But why is this solution depedant of the number of results in my database?

Comment: Only because it would get a sample of the matching terms and not necessarily all of them. The highlighting will only return matches relevant to the query (including the number of rows returned). So if you have a lot of records in your Solr core, it's possible, even likely, that you won't be able to retrieve **all** of the matching terms using this method. You could try to return all rows but that would be a lot of data for a task that is ostensibly pretty simple. I hope I'm explaining myself well.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your time, experience and good will.

Comment: Thank you for excellent questions! You really made me think on this one.

Comment: @DavidFaber same reason Im also here!